# VBS: Using WSHNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter without a print server

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to create a simple VBS logon script that sets the default printer for users logging into Server 2003 through a terminal server environment.  The printer is a network printer that is not going through a print server.  It's DNS name is "Front MailRoom Printer" and port is \192.168.0.82.

The script I have is this:

```
Set WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WSHNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "Front MailRoom Printer"
```

When it runs, an error 80070002 (the system cannot find the file specified) points to line 2 character 1 comes up.  Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This was a user profile issue that impacted printers, not an issue with the code itself.  If anyone cares, this registry key didn't exist for the user:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

Once it was added added and user logged off and back on, the root issue was resolved and script ran successfully.